# Is it possible record audio from multiple sources in android studio

Tags: android, audio

I am working on a simple audio recording application in android studio, I am trying to capture low frequency, low amplitude sounds using a google pixel 8. I currently have the audio source set to the microphone:

mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

And I was wondering if it Is possible to record the audio using all of the speakers in the device (in this case there are three), As appose to just one. Is there any way to achieve this in android studio directly?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Android Developper documentation, this shouldn't be possible with **MediaRecorder** directly. At API level 26+, they recommend using **MediaMuxer** to record simultaneously different Audio channels.

https://developer.android.com/media/platform/mediarecorder

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer